# In -App Updates not able to retrieve the old version intent object from Google Play Store

Tags: android

Using the below code:

private void checkUpdate() {

```
    final AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
            startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if  (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS){
            startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo);
            // Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void startUpdateFlow(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
    try {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, this.IMMEDIATE_APP_UPDATE_REQ_CODE);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == IMMEDIATE_APP_UPDATE_REQ_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update canceled by user! Result Code: " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update success! Result Code: " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Failed! Result Code: " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            checkUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Toast.makeText(this, "Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); is not showing any update although the version installed in my device is lower than the version available in the store

Comment: Did you try the FakeAppUpdateManager class provided by the Google

Comment: Yes - I did but it did not work. Do we need to do anything in Google Play Store apart from just uploading the signed bundle aab. The Toast also does not appear.

Comment: It is working fine with Internal App Sharing but is taking too long for the Google Play Store to push notifications to individual devices. Later I found that I got the update after 2 days of my updating the app on Google Play Store.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but for my apps, I am using a pipeline and I can set the in-app update priority. To determine priority, Google Play uses an integer value between 0 and 5, with 0 being the default, and 5 being the highest priority. Priority can only be set when rolling out a new release, and cannot be changed later.

Comment: Thanks Dear - Can you guide me the step by step procedure - how to set the priority. I believe it will be of great help and sort out my issue.

Comment: I use Azure devops for my build automation and use a plugin in the pipeline for the upload to playstore. You might need to create a service account and link it to the steps in the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use fakeAppUpdateManager for testing out this

something like this :

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    appUpdateManager = FakeAppUpdateManager(baseContext)
    appUpdateManager.setUpdateAvailable(2)
 } else {
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(baseContext)
 }
```